# How to pass additional parameter to Ajax response while sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a jquery function which iterates through an array and calls servlet  for each iteration. How can I make sure that the response from each servlet goes to respective div section. The div id is unique and corresponds to val in an array.

JQuery:

```
function foo() {

  for (var p in obj) {

    var tagId = obj[p]["prop1"];

    $.get('CallServlet', {
      json: JSON.stringify(obj[p])
    }, function(response) {
      $("#" + tagId).append(response);
    });

  }
}
```

Example:

```
tagId= obj[0][val1];
```

I want my response to go to :

```
<div id="tagId"></div>
```

In my function above the value of the tagId in the response is overwritten when the iterater advances through the objects.
When I receive the response for `obj[0]`, the tagId is updated to  `obj[1][val1]`

Comment: you do ajax inside the loop and when response return function take the last value of tagId, so you need to look at solution i provide to you using IIEF function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap it with the function with IIFE

```
function foo() {

  for (var p in obj) {

    var tagId = obj[p]["prop1"];
    (function(id) {
      $.get('CallServlet', {
        json: JSON.stringify(obj[p])
      }, function(response) {
        printFunc(responseText, id);
      });
    })(tagId)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're sending your ajax call in a loop, you can use the loop variable in the callback for your ajax call.

```
function(response){
    $("#"+tagId).append(response);
}
```

This will generate one different callback function for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: I'm already using the loop variable "tagId". Since the iterater is incremented before the response, the tagID is updated to the next value before receiving the response.

Comment: I think he's saying that, (because "closure"), tagId is available in your function w/o passing it as a param.